# Merging from parent branch, did hg incoming path/to/baseline, how do I just merge?

Tags: mercurial, merge

I'm in my branch, and I do this:

```
hg incoming /path/to/baseline
```

And I get a few changesets in the output.

Now do I just merge to pull in the changsets to my branch?

```
hg merge /path/to/baseline
```

Will my history show what was merged?
As long as I didn't touch those files, it will be automatic right?

Answer (score 2):

You should really try all this out yourself! Make a couple of test repositories:

```
hg init main
hg clone main clone
```

and then experiment away. It's easy and safe since you're only playing around on your own machine. (This is actually what happens "behind the scenes" when you ask a question here: I try to make sure that the advice I give really works, so I normally have to run a few tests on a new repository to double-check.)

If you ran the tests, you would see that

1. You cannot give `hg merge` a path name (or URL) as argument. It takes a *revision* as the only argument. You need to `hg pull /path/to/baseline` to copy the changesets into your local repository and then `hg merge`.
2. The history will indeed show what was merged. A merge becomes a *merge commit* in Mercurial. That is a changeset with two ancestor changesets — both lines of development leading up to the merge are still in the repository.
3. Merges are without conflicts ("automatic") if the changes made in the two branhces don't overlap. If you edit different files in the two branches then there's certainly no overlap. But you can also edit different regions within the same file and still have a merge without conflicts.

There is a fine tutorial on [the wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Tutorial) and I've also written a [beginners guide](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/). I hope that helps.